# Launch EC2 instances using Ansible and assign subnets dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, vpc

Hi I have a requirement to write an Ansible code to launch EC2 instances and assign them to available subnets in round robin fashion. There is only 1 VPC which is created manually, however the number of subnets would change depending on the infrastructure getting launched.
My hosts file looks like this

```
[ABC-database]
ABCDB01

[ABC-application]
ABCFE0[1:2]
ABCBE0[1:2]

[cassandra]
CASS0[1:3]
```

I have also written code to create a subnet file

```
subnet1: subnet-7284c12b
subnet2: subnet-fd363e98
subnet3: subnet-c892bfbf
```

What I have to do is pick up one instance at a time, pick up each instances' configurations from all.yml and keep assigning it to each subnet in a cyclic(round robin) fashion.

Currently I have written a shell script to do this. the script counts the number of subnets in the subnet file and returns a new subnet id every time it is called.

I am stuck after this.
**How should i call this script while launching ec2 instances?** the below code throws an error 'next_subnet' is undefined

```
- name: Launch instances.
  local_action:
    command: ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
    register: next_subnet
    module: ec2
    region: "{{ region }}"
    keypair: "{{ keypair }}"
    instance_type: "{{item.instance_type}}"
    image: "{{image_id}}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ next_subnet.stdout }}"
    count: 1
    wait: yes
  with_items: "{{component_list}}"
```

Is there a less messy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your playbook has got two tasks merged into one so the `next_subnet` variable is not registered when you try to run the `ec2` task.

Changing your playbook to this resolves that immediate issue:

```
- name: Get next subnet
  local_action:
    command: ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
    register: next_subnet

- name: Launch instances
  local_action:
    ec2:
      region: "{{ region }}"
      keypair: "{{ keypair }}"
      instance_type: "{{item.instance_type}}"
      image: "{{image_id}}"
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ next_subnet.stdout }}"
      count: 1
      wait: yes
  with_items: "{{component_list}}"
```

However, that then only makes the playbook run rather than being what you want. If you up the `count` amount each instance still be put in the same subnet as the `next_subnet` variable is registered just once and then you use it in a loop.

Assuming you can keep calling your script over and over and it will rotate through the available subnet ids then you simply need to iterate the first task to get a list of results which you can use with the second task like this:

```
- name: Get next subnet
  local_action:
    command: ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
    register: next_subnet
  with_items: component_list

- name: Launch instances
  local_action:
    ec2:
      region: "{{ region }}"
      keypair: "{{ keypair }}"
      instance_type: "{{item.1.instance_type}}"
      image: "{{image_id}}"
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.0.stdout }}"
      count: 1
      wait: yes
  with_together: 
    - next_subnet
    - component_list
```

Presuming your shell script outputs something like this:

```
$ ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
subnet-7284c12b
$ ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
subnet-fd363e98
$ ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
subnet-c892bfbf
$ ./get_next_available_subnet.sh
subnet-7284c12b
```

Then the first task will register the variable of `next_subnet` with a list of task results which will have a key of `stdout` and the value of a subnet id. The second task then uses a [with_together loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) to loop through that list of subnet ids along with the list of instances.